# Boolean equality over natural numbers in Coq

Tags: coq

Is it possible to compare two natural numbers, x and y, in Coq, and have the equality be returned as a boolean value? Ideally I would like to be able to do something like:

```
Variable x : nat.
Variable y : nat.

if bool_eq x y
  then ...
  else ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Coq is very similar to Haskell or OCaml. A function like that is defined in [Coq.Arith.EqNat](http://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Arith.EqNat.html). It's called `beq_nat`.